# Smart quotes converted to straight quotes when C# writes to stdout redirected to file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# console application which writes a string containing smart quotes to stdout via Console.WriteLine. I run the program from a command window and redirect the output to a file.
In the file, the smart quotes have been replaced by normal ASCII straight quotes.

Here's a simplified version that exhibits the problem:

```
class Quotes
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
        System.Console.WriteLine("\u201cIn Quotes\u201d");
}
```

Which I'd run per:

```
quotes.exe >output.txt
```

My environment:

- .NET Framework 4.8 (although it also happens with .NET 5)
- Windows 10
- Normal CMD.EXE, Windows Terminal, Powershell ISE (same behavior on all three)

I'd like to understand where in the flow the translation is occurring and why.  Is it .NET?  Is it the shell's redirect?  I'm accustomed to bash on Linux and MacOS where I've piped/redirected non-ASCII data untampered many times, so I didn't expect to open the resulting file here and find the data altered.

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` -- Note that it will probably change the file format.